# sqlite3 - Merge multiple rows as one row where id is same

Tags: sqlite, merge, duplicates, rows

I has a problem:

In my `SQLite` (`sqlite3 on android`) database I have a table like so:

```
id  | text
---------------------
id1:
abcdhgjj

id1:
kjhjmnl

id1:
mnbvjgfh

id2:
lhghdb

id2:
ghduhjgf
```

and I'd like to get to:

```
id  | text
---------------------
id1:
abcdhgjj
kjhjmnl
mnbvjgfh

id2:
lhghdb
ghduhjgf
```

How can i do it Using `SQLite` Query??

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: i shoul say that, i'd like to merge text fields with ENTER character (multi row text).

Answer (score 9):

SQLite supports `group_concat()`, so you can try:

```
select id, group_concat(text, ' ') as text
from table t
group by id;
```

Note that you have no control over the order of the concatenation.

EDIT:

You should be able to enter a newline directly into the query:

```
 SELECT id, group_concat(text, '') AS text
 FROM table t
 group by id;
```

Comment: thanks gordon. can i put enter character instead of '   ' ?.  and if you say me yes, what is the enter character?

Comment: This isn't working. Kindly check and reply

Comment: @NehemiahNarzary . . . This is a rather old question.  If you have a question about *your* data, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT id,
group_concat(text, '<br>') as text
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY I'd;
```

This worked for me.